# Magento 2 : I want to validate post code with 6 digit in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I want to validate the post code exact 6 digit.
Means user can not add more than or less than 6 digits.
And this I need in checkout page of Magento 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, It's work for me

Create new validation rule

Create **registration.php** file here **app/code/RS/Validation/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'RS_Validation',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create **module.xml** file here **app/code/RS/Validation/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="RS_Validation" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Create **rsvalidation.js** file here **app/code/RS/Validation/view/frontend/web/js/rsvalidation.js**

```
define([
   'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator',
   'jquery',
   'jquery/ui',
   'jquery/validate',
   'mage/translate'
], function(validator,$){ 
    'use strict';

    return function() {
        $.validator.addMethod(
        'rspostcode', function (value, element) { 
        console.log(value.length);
        return value.length > 5 &&  value.length < 7 && value.match(/[0-9]/);
        }, $.mage.__('Input 6 digit postcode')); 

        validator.addRule(
        'rspostcode', function (value, element) { 
        console.log(value.length);
        return value.length > 5 &&  value.length < 7 && value.match(/[0-9]/);
        },$.mage.__('Input 6 digit postcode')
        );
    }
});
```

Create **requirejs-config.js** file here  **app/code/RS/Validation/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
       "*": {
           "rsvalidation": "RS_Validation/js/rsvalidation"
       }
   }
};
```

Add validation rule to checkout postcode create file **checkout_index_index.xml** file here **app/code/RS/Validation/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">                               
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                           
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array"> 
                                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                          
                                                                    <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="validate-digits" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                                                                            <item name="rspostcode" xsi:type="string">true</item>     
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>               
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>                                            
                                        </item>
                                    </item>                                    
                                </item>
                            </item>                            
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

replace script in **onepage.phtml** from **app/design/frontend/Vendorname/Themename/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml**

replace script

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{            
    "#checkout": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
    }
}
</script>
```

**to**

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#checkout": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsLayout();?>
        },
        "*": {
            "RS_Validation/js/rsvalidation" : {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Enjoy !!!